# Counting elements skipped using Reap & Sow

Tags: list-manipulation

I am using the following code to filter data based on the percentage change between points.

```
Reap[z = data[[1]]; Sow[z]; 
         Scan[If[Abs[# - z]/z > delta, 
         z = #; Sow[z]] &, data]][[2, 1]]
```

That is, only considering point that were separated but a certain percentage change.

While it gives me the correct answer, I would like to count the values that are dropped in between each selected point.

How could I do that ?

Comment: Have you considered using `Sow` with a tag (i.e. a second argument to `Sow`)? Plus, do you want to count the number of dropped values? Adding a test set of data and expected output always helps...

Comment: @Yves, this is exactly what I want to do, but I am yet uncomfortable with Sow[]. The output is opaque to me.

Comment: @R.M I changed the tag from compress to compression because it sounds like a RLE question.

Comment: @R.M. : By data compression I mean reducing a data set. trying to keep its most meaningful component. In this case I am looking at a financial time series. And I assume that movements under a certain % are irrelevant. Not worth keeping for the analysis I conduct.

Comment: @500 Thanks, Yves' explanation made it clear :) While I now understand its meaning here, I'm not sure if it's necessary... Others can chime in if they think otherwise

Comment: Side topic: you can shorten your code by replacing `z = #; Sow[z]` with `Sow[z = #]`

Comment: @R.M perhaps it could be tagged with "run-length encoding", but the question should be tuned to reflect that.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard, Thank You !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to count the dropped values, for each application of your *distance* function you have exactly one outcome. Either the value is fine and included in you list or the value is dropped.

In my opinion a simpler approach is to not use `Reap` and `Sow`. Instead, use a simple `Map` and transform the list afterwards. Furthermore, you have to note that your first element is always dropped because you set `z` to your first element of the list and get zero in the numerator of your distance function.

Maybe a better approach is here to *not* include the first element of the list manually but to fix the initial value of `z`. If your data is always positive, you could do for instance

```
Block[{z = First[data]/(2 + delta)},
 If[Abs[# - z]/z > delta, z = #; z, Dropped] & /@ data
 ]
```

Test this in comparison with your function:

```
data = {7, 1, 8, 9, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 9, 2, 7, 3, 9, 7, 1, 10, 3};
delta = .4;

Block[{z = First[data]/(2 + delta)},
 If[Abs[# - z]/z > delta, z = #; z, Dropped] & /@ data
]

(* 
{7, 1, 8, Dropped, Dropped, 3, 1, 2, 4, Dropped, 7, Dropped, 2, 7, 3, 
 9, Dropped, 1, 10, 3}
*)
```

Now the only thing you have to do is to gather all `Dropped` symbols, count them and give the other list as your result:

```
myfilter[data_] := {#1, "Dropped" -> Length[#2]} & @@
  GatherBy[Block[{z = First[data]/(2 + delta)},
    If[Abs[# - z]/z > delta, z = #; z, Dropped] & /@ data
    ], # === Dropped &]
```

and then

```
In[68]:= myfilter[data]

Out[68]= {{7, 1, 8, 3, 1, 2, 4, 7, 2, 7, 3, 9, 1, 10, 3}, 
 "Dropped" -> 5}
```

**Update**

If you want to build a list where you *see* where and how many drops happened you could leave out the `GatherBy` thing and work on the number list with the `Dropped` inside. Example:

```
data = {7, 1, 8, 9, 6, 3, 1, 2, 4, 3, 7, 9, 2, 7, 3, 9, 7, 1, 10, 3};
delta = .4;

res = Block[{z = First[data]/(2 + delta)}, 
 If[Abs[# - z]/z > delta, z = #; z, Dropped] & /@ data]

Split[res, #1 === #2 === Dropped &] /. 
   {{i_Integer} :> i, d : {Dropped ..} :> {Length[d]}}

(*
{7, 1, 8, {2}, 3, 1, 2, 4, {1}, 7, {1}, 2, 7, 3, 9, {1}, 1, 10, 3}
*)
```

I packed the drop-length information inside list braces so one sees what is output and what is drop-information.
Note, when I see this right the second argument to `Split` is not necessary because it cannot happen that there are same numbers next to each other.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I have yet not been able to obtain all the "dropped" count in between the chosen one. That is I want a list with all the selected and the corresponding list of the number of dropped value in between 2 selected ones. My attempts using "Position" suffer from possible duplicates. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
ignored = 0;
Reap[z = data[[1]]; Sow[z]; 
     Scan[
      If[Abs[# - z]/z > delta, 
         z = #; Sow[z],
         ignored++
      ]&, 
      data
     ]
][[2, 1]]
```

where I am using the false branch of `If` to increment the `ignored` counter.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variation on rcollyer's method - sowing the elements that satisfy the condition as well as lists containing the number of skipped elements and the position of the last skipped element:

```
    data = RandomInteger[{1, 10}, {100}];
    pos = 0;
    delta = .40;
    skipped = {};
    Reap[z = data[[1]]; Sow[z];
    Scan[(If[Abs[# - z]/z > delta,
      z = #; pos++; 
      If[skipped =!= {}, Sow[{Length@skipped, pos}]]; 
      skipped = {}; Sow[Style[z, Red, Bold, 18]], 
     pos++; skipped = AppendTo[skipped, #]]) &, Rest@data]][[2, 1]]
```

gives

[image]

To verify the results, if you replace `Sow[{Length@skipped, pos}]` with `Sow[#] & /@ skipped` you get

[image]